# Docker image building CACHED problem (Spring boot)

Tags: spring, docker, dockerfile

I am building a docker image for spring boot project. When i built first time it copied files and with build command build the project, but an error came and build was failed. So i made few changes to the files. But when i am running the docker build command  `docker build -t image .` its giving CACHED for most of the things like the sub modules of the project which i changed, so they are unable to change in the docker image.

```
CACHED [ 7/14] COPY core core                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/14] COPY settings.gradle settings.gradle                     0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/14] COPY build.gradle build.gradle                           0.0s
 => CACHED [10/14] COPY gradlew gradlew                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [11/14] COPY gradle gradle                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [12/14] COPY version.txt version.txt
```

So the changes i made are not reflecting in the image, so its giving me the same error again and again.
I tried to clear the cache with commands like `docker system prune -a` but the cache is not removing from there.

Also, have tried `--no-cache` but it did not solve the problem

Comment: have you tried `docker build -t --no-cache image . `?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried, but it will only prevent saving cache in the current operation but will use cache of previous operations. @tentative

Comment: `—no-cache` should disable the build cache entirely, not just prevent it from storing a new cache. Can you post the contents of your Dockerfile? It sounds like you’ve tried most of the normal methods to bust the cache, it must either be an issue with your Dockerfile, or the files you’re copying over haven’t actually changed. Posting the error you’re seeing when you try to run may also be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried this `docker builder prune -a`? The [builder command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_prune/) removes the build cache whereas `docker system prune -a` [removes already built containers, networks, etc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/).

Answer (score -2):

You can try uninstalling docker and reinstalling it again. See if that helps?